# Display post details by post ID

Tags: get-posts, frontpage, post-meta

I need to display post details by ID on front page template (`front-page.php`).

On the front page I want to display the post’s title, excerpt & featured image. I have tried to do that but no idea on how I should be doing that.

Is there any function in WordPress that can be used to do it?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) for that

Example:

```
<?php
$post = get_post($id); //assuming $id has been initialized
setup_postdata($post);

// display the post here
the_title();
the_excerpt();
the_post_thumbnail();

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```